# How to make an anonymous call using Flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout, anonymous-function, flutter-dependencies, phone-call, flutter-plugin

I want to develop a Flutter app. In that,

- There will be a list of customers and employees
- The call placed by an employee to the customer need to be anonymous
- The employee should not view the customer number